# Radio without antenna?

Tags: antenna

Is it possible that there will ever be a radio system that does not require antennas? (Not small embedded antennas for microwave radios, but radios that actually do not have antennas)

Comment: What do you mean by an "antenna"? All devices that deliberately transmit or receive radio waves need a mechanism to couple to the electromagnetic field. That's conventionally what we call an antenna; to that extent, it's almost the defining characteristic of a radio system.

Comment: sounds like a cable modem :-)

Comment: (what I mean is that most high-speed **wired** data links — USB and Thunderbolt, twisted-pair and even fiber Ethernet, DSL/DOCSIS, etc. —  rely on a lot of radio-adjacent *principles* like modulated high frequency carrier waves and information/signal coding theory, but instead of sending and receiving communications via an antenna they try to keep the signals only in/out of a transmission line.)

Answer (score 4):

Radio without antenna?  That's like a sound card without a speaker.

The radio has to have an antenna or there is no way to receive or transmit the radio waves.  However, there's lots of ways to hide the antenna, especially in a receiver.  As you suggest, it can be small and embedded -- and not just for microwave.  Even AM antennas (wavelength ~600m) can have embedded antennas in the form of coils wrapped around a ferrite rod.  FM broadcast receivers frequently use the earphone wire as an antenna.  The metal case can in some cases act like an antenna.  Handheld radios with monopole antennas are actually using the person holding the radio as half of the antenna.

Radios need antennas to work.  It's a critical part.

Comment: Cell phones used to use visible, in some cases extendible antennas, then they discovered fractal antennas, essentially a folded slot antenna, which can be hidden inside the device's housing.

Comment: Indeed. An RF circuit that omits the antenna means you have an RF circuit that'll try to find anything it can use as an antenna with varying results.

Comment: Modern cell phones also use higher frequencies than old ones, which corresponds to smaller antennas that can fit inside the phone.  They also use a higher density cell towers and thus can use lower power, which also allows smaller and less efficient antennas.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by the terms "radio" and "antenna".  But one can connect an RF transmitter circuit with an RF receiver circuit, both in shielded metal cases, using coax.  With good quality coax and SMA connectors, there is usually very little RF leakage.  But there might be some detectable EM leakage, for which the radiating surfaces could count as being an antenna.

Paired stripline traces embedded on inner layers of a PCB could also connect a transmitter and a receiver on the same circuit board, and allow the receiver to receive.  Transmission lines and antennas are usually considered to be separate items.

If atoms+electrons can be considered antennas, no.  As I am not sure whether the atoms inside optical comm or RF circuits can be considered antennas.

Comment: So it might be possible with devices physically connected to each other, but not with wireless devices?

Comment: The energy has to go somewhere to be useful.  Either it goes down a transmission line and into another device or an antenna, or it just warms up the transmitter without doing anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Sorta kinda maybe, but not in the way you're probably imagining.

The purposes of an antenna can include:

- to convert energy from one form (typically free space radiation) to another (typically electric potential signals in, say, copper) OR the other way around
- manage directivity for the purpose of increasing signal efficiency in a particular direction or use case (again, TX or RX)
- first stage selectivity for rejecting unwanted or noise signals
- constructive signal amplification (in the case of an array or other system with gain with respect to isotropy)

A system without an antenna is merely a homogenous signal medium... very much like a circuit. No need for an antenna inside a circuit that has traces for example.

Anyway, thanks for entertaining this off the cuff answer.